# I made an encryption program, how can I make it detect longer strings on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I recently made a simple program that can take any letters defined in the map, and replace them with whatever they are assigned to, and vise-versa. For example if you enter welcome to my code it would output as: ˆ´®¬∆©´ ˙∆ ©œ ¬∆≈´

The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map = {
  "a" : "π",
  "b" : "∫",
  "c" : "¬",
  "d" : "≈",
  "e" : "´",
  "f" : "Ω",
  "g" : "å",
  "h" : "√",
  "i" : "ç",
  "j" : "∂",
  "k" : "˚",
  "l" : "®",
  "m" : "©",
  "n" : "†",
  "o" : "∆",
  "p" : "ø",
  "q" : "¨",
  "r" : "µ",
  "s" : "ƒ",
  "t" : "˙",
  "u" : "¥",
  "v" : "ß",
  "w" : "ˆ",
  "x" : "∑",
  "y" : "œ",
  "z" : "˜",
  " " : " "
}

function main() {
    var input = prompt("Enter a string!");
    var encrypted = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
       if(map[input[i]]){
          encrypted += map[input[i]];
       }
    } 
    document.write(encrypted);
}

main()
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It can output as long as a string as I want, but it can only output a, b, c... x, y, and z.

Ideally, in order to make it easier, I want to make it detect longer random strings like Mfdshs so I do not have to worry about repeating letters. How can I get it to detect for the capitol letter then all the lowercase letters, and find what letter that is assigned to? Not just the one letter replacement.

What I mean is, is the map would look like this:

```
var map = {
  "a" : "Wgbf",
  "b" : "Gvhs",
  "c" : "Bgty",
  "d" : "Dafd",
  "e" : "Ihkj",
  "f" : "Hjuk",
  "g" : "Byfg",
  "h" : "Hynk",
  "i" : "Afds",
  "j" : "Njio",
  "k" : "Yipl",
  "l" : "Wetv",
  "m" : "Obth",
  "n" : "Cbhg",
  "o" : "Kolp",
  "p" : "Pnya",
  "q" : "Fnpd",
  "r" : "Buip",
  "s" : "Gknp",
  "t" : "Lnug",
  "u" : "Fuih",
  "v" : "Vylp",
  "w" : "Fnng",
  "x" : "Bhyh",
  "y" : "Kkgh",
  "z" : "Xnvx",
  " " : "Rgyb"
}
```

And vise-versa.

Comment: `string.substr` ?

Comment: This is an encoding, not an encryption.

Comment: @Bergi it's an encryption if the map is secret

Comment: @Touffy Yeah, but still [a pretty weak one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) then

Comment: I assume OP knows that. Probably meant as an exercise rather than a real-world crypto application (I hope).

Comment: that is true. If I want it to be more secure, I will make it that way. This is just an exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is shown in code below but it is a bit slow. To make it work values of object `map` (key) can not include one another. Secret strings with differerent lengths should also work correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = {
    "a": "Wgbf",
    "b": "Gvhs",
    "c": "Bgty",
    "d": "Dafd",
    "e": "Ihkj",
    "f": "Hjuk",
    "g": "Byfg",
    "h": "Hynk",
    "i": "Afds",
    "j": "Njio",
    "k": "Yipl",
    "l": "Wetv",
    "m": "Obth",
    "n": "Cbhg",
    "o": "Kolp",
    "p": "Pnya",
    "q": "Fnpd",
    "r": "Buip",
    "s": "Gknp",
    "t": "Lnug",
    "u": "Fuih",
    "v": "Vylp",
    "w": "Fnng",
    "x": "Bhyh",
    "y": "Kkgh",
    "z": "Xnvx",
    " ": "Rgyb"
}
function encode(input){
    var encrypted = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
       if(map[input[i]]){
          encrypted += map[input[i]];
       }
    } 
    return encrypted;
}

function decode(input) {
    var enc = ''+input;
    var result = '';
    do {
        for (const key of Object.keys(map)) {
            var value = map[key];
            if (enc.startsWith(value)) {
                result += key;
                enc = enc.substr(value.length);
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (enc.length > 0);
 return result;
}

function encClick(){
 var e = encode(document.getElementById("plain").value);
 document.getElementById("encodedRes").innerHTML = e;
}
function decClick(){
 var e = decode(document.getElementById("encoded").value);
 document.getElementById("decodedRes").innerHTML = e;
}
function encPrompt(){
 var input = prompt("Enter text", "work ing");
 var e = encode(input);
 document.getElementById("promptResult").innerHTML = e;
}
function decPrompt(){
 var input = prompt("Enter cipher", "FnngKolpBuipYiplRgybAfdsCbhgByfg");
 var e = decode(input);
 document.getElementById("promptResult").innerHTML = e;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
 <span id="promptResult"></span><br>
<button onclick="encPrompt()">Prompt encode</button><button onclick="decPrompt()">Prompt decode</button><br><br><br>

<input id="plain" type="text" name="" value="work ing" />
<button onclick="encClick()">Encode</button><span id="encodedRes"></span><br><br>

<input id="encoded" type="text" name="" value="FnngKolpBuipYiplRgybAfdsCbhgByfg" />
<button onclick="decClick()">Decode</button><span id="decodedRes"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I've edited this answer and added html gui.

Comment: This seems like it works, but where would I put it into my code if I wanted to be able to use a custom input? Right now all I do to encode and decode is reverse the map. 

How could I make it so it prompts me for an input, I enter something, copy it, then I reverse the map and enter what the first code said, and finnaly it outputs what I put in?

Comment: @Kyle I've edited my answer. See if that's what you meant.

Comment: It works! Thanks for creating this for me. A little bit complicated for me, but I can use it to learn new things!

Answer (score 0):

If the substitutions are all the same length, you could split the string into 4-character substrings and loop through the resulting array. Finding an implementation on StackOverflow is left as an exercise to the reader. I promise it's out there.

You could also turn the string into an ArrayBuffer and manipulate it as binary data (which is what all real crypto functions do), which would allow you to read 4 bytes as a single Number:

```
cypherInput = "IhkjBhyhWgbfObthPnyaWetvIhkj"
buffer = new TextEncoder().encode(cypherInput).buffer
words = new Uint32Array(buffer) // reinterpret the buffer
cleartext = words.map(word => /* map each possible 32-bit word to a character */)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the substitutions are *not* always 4-character words, you would ideally do this with something a like a [Finite-state transducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer). JavaScript only does finite state automata for you (i.e. RegEx) so let's work with that (assuming you're only using ASCII letters in your code words):

```
cypherInput.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g)
```

that will return an array with all the code words. Then there are several ways to produce the cleartext, one of which would be to use `replace` with a mapping function as the second argument instead of explicitly looping over the matches:

```
cypherInput.replace(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g, word => /* your mapping function */)
```

If you want to use non-ASCII in your code, expressing the set of initial letters in a RegEx may become a lot of work rather quickly.